# refreshin page get by request dispatch filter is giving me error?

Tags: jsp, servlets

Hi I wrote the following code in /ManagerServlet(ManagerServlet.java)

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws IOException
    String strId=request.getParameter("id");
    Integer id=Integer.parseInt(strId);

    if(id !=null)
    {
        Manager manager=null;
        IAdminDAO dao=AdminDAO.getDAO();
        manager=dao.ManagerGET(id);
        request.setAttribute("manager", manager);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("newManager.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
    else
    {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("newManager.jsp").forward(request, response);  
    }

    }
```

Here i am going to page if I call the servlet and going to newManager.jsp but if I refresh the jsp page again it is going to servlet ManagerServlet and getting null Point exception at Integer.parseInt(strId).. How can i avoid this problem

Comment: If you get a `NullPoiterException` at `Integer id=Integer.parseInt(strId);` then, that request parameter with the name `id` is unavailable. How do you pass that parameter?

Comment: If you want to forward to a different resource (`newManager.jsp`), when `strId` is `null` then, consider moving this line `Integer id=Integer.parseInt(strId);` inside the `if` block and change this `if(id !=null)` condition to `if(istrId !=null)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is using get method instead of post method to send data to your servlet.

If you're sending several data to your servlet, that's better to use `session` (you can refresh in this case without losing data). For example if you want send an object to another page/servlet use session instead of post/get; because in-order to send an object through post/get, for example you should convert your object to json format.

**Note**: Also when you send some information by post to a servlet, when you refresh this page, browser ask you to send post information again.

Comment: if i set any attributes (request.setAttribute method) to newmanager.jsp will that available in new Page ?

Comment: If you make a redirect those request attributes will not available to the page where the request has been redirected (it is a brand new request). All you need to do is pass those request attributes as query-string parameters and grab them using `request.getParameter("paramName");`. @VikasReddy

Comment: thank you .. but the problem is i need to send more data to jsp.. In above code i am setting one pojo class .. is there ant other alternative ?

Comment: If you have some composite/complex objects like POJOs and still need to redirect (thus not forward/dispatch), basically the only way to obtain them from the target resource (which the request is redirected to) is to set those objects as a session attribute and **remove them from the session after use**. @VikasReddy

Comment: Tq@Tiny and @Ali Sepehri.kh